# Factorization of $x^8-x$ over $F_2$ and $F_4$

Tags: finite-fields, factoring

How can I factorize $x^8-x$ over the fields $F_2$ and $F_4$?

Comment: What have you tried? And what do you know of the relationship between the polynomials of the form $x^{p^n}-x$ and the elements of the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: Hint: $8 = 2^3$ which should tell you something....

Comment: I know that x^p^n-x is the product of all irred. polynomials in this field, correct?

Comment: 8 should be the number of elements in that field!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** We have that $x^8-x$ splits as
$$ x(x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1)$$
over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\gcd(x^8-x,x^4-x)=x^2+x=x(x+1)$.

Comment: Ok, in the first line we have the factorization over F2. Is there a strategy to find this out? What do mean exactly with the gcd of x^8-x and x^4-x in this context?

Comment: @Ovomaltine: over $\mathbb{F}_p$, $\gcd(p(x),x^{p^h}-x)$ gives the product of all the irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F_p}$, having degree $d\mid h$, that divide $p(x)$.

Comment: And what about the factoriziation over F4?

Comment: Ovomaltine, the factorization over $F_4$ is the same as it is over $F_2$. Those cubics have no zeros in $F_4$ (those zeros are in $F_8\setminus F_2$), so they remain irreducible over $F_4$. A more general result is that an irreducible polynomial of degree $m$ over $F_2$ remains irreducible over $F_{2^n}$, iff $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Proving that more general version takes a bit more theory (e.g. basic Galois theory).

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer to "Is there a strategy to find this out?" referring to the
factorization shown in Jack D'Aurizio's answer.

In *this case*, the factorization is easy to discover by simple calculations.
First, we note that there are no repeated roots since $x^8-x$ and its formal
derivative $8x^7-1 = -1$ are relatively prime polynomials. Next, we have the obvious factorization
$$\begin{align}x^8-x &= x(x-1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)\\
&= x(x+1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
\end{align}$$
where the factors of $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ (if any)
must be irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ or more; we have 
already accounted for all the
degree-$1$ factors of $x^8-x$. Now, the only irreducible quadratic 
is $x^2+x+1$ (all other quadratic polynomials have $x$ or $x+1$ as 
factors), and it is
easy to verify (by inspection, almost!) that $x^2+x+1$ does not divide
$x^6 + x^5 +\cdots+ x + 1$.  Turning to cubic polynomials,
we can discard $x^3+1$ and $x^3+x^2+x+1$ as possible candidates
since they both have $x+1$ as a factor. So we are left with irreducible cubic $x^3+x^2+1$ and
$x^3+x+1$ as possibilities, and it is with much joy and satisfaction that
we verify that their product does indeed equal 
$x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ giving us that
$$x^8-x = x(x-1)(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1).\tag{1}$$